# How to install gcc/g++ 9 on CentOS 7 docker (centos:7)

Tags: docker, gcc, centos7

In order to use the C++17 include `<filesystem>` I need gcc-9 package in my centos 7 docker.

By default [centos:7](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos)  will install gcc 4.8.5 from the regular distro repo.

```sh
docker run --rm -it centos:7
# yum install -y gcc
# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
```

Is there any way to easily install a gcc-9 (or later) package (i.e. not build it from source)

Thanks !

note: need gcc-9 to have good C++17 `<filesystem>` support.
GCC 9 Release note:

> Using the types and functions in `<filesystem>` does not require linking with `-lstdc++fs` now.

src: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What I have so far:

cat Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7 AS env

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl
RUN yum install -y devtoolset-9

RUN echo "source /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/enable" >> /etc/bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
RUN gcc --version
```

So you must:

1. Add the source stuff in a bashrc
   note: On Centos it's `/etc/bashrc` while on ubuntu it's `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. Update the docker default shell to be bash AND to "load" the bashrc using `--login`

### Output

```sh
docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/32 : FROM centos:7 AS env
 ---> 8652b9f0cb4c
Step 2/32 : RUN yum update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2bb269cd8dc
Step 3/32 : RUN yum install -y centos-release-scl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1184e26c71cf
Step 4/32 : RUN yum install -y devtoolset-9
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e678665d2a4e
Step 5/32 : RUN echo "source /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/enable" >> /etc/bashrc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe1745d4ca87
Step 6/32 : SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
 ---> Running in 2dd7955f4487
Removing intermediate container 2dd7955f4487
 ---> 3cf4835bf680
Step 7/32 : RUN gcc --version
 ---> Running in b5de3266d607
gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 ...
```

### What won't work

#### Test 1

```
RUN scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
RUN gcc --version | head -1
```

each `RUN` is a new shell so the sub-bash is lost on the second line.

#### Test 2

```
RUN source /opt/rh/devtoolset-9/enable && gcc --version | head -1
RUN gcc --version | head -1
```

Here again the source is only for the first RUN shell command but will be lost...

#### Test 3

This may work but with potential unexpected behaviour

```
ENV PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/bin:$PATH
RUN gcc --version | head -1
```

here we only "fix" the `PATH` variable but if you look at the `/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/enable` script there is so more to do than only updating the `PATH`...

Answer (score 0):

You may give it a try using the below steps if that may help:
Download the latest package from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-9.2.0/

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-9.2.0/gcc-9.2.0.tar.gz
```

Extract the files using the steps below:

```
tar -xzvf gcc-9.20.tar.gz
cd gcc-9.2.0
```

Build a configuration using the below,

```
./configure
```

Compile the installation using make and then make install.

```
make 
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-rh-2-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-2-3.el7.centos.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install devtoolset-9-gcc-c++

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).